# MySQL NOT LIKE NULL

Tags: mysql

MySQL Query:

select 'id' AS 'member_id', 'pd00'
from 'mbr'
where 'pd00' NOT LIKE '';

NOT LIKE Baulks Why?

It is also underlined in the control panel as a bad statement under NOT LIKE..

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If that's your query then you don't need to use `LIKE` operator. Rather use `!=` operator like

```
select 'id' AS 'member_id', 
'pd00' from `mbr` 
where 'pd00' <> '';
```

Again the condition `'pd00' <> ''` is unnecessary cause it's will be true (Tautology) and hence can be ignored as well.

Not sure if those are column names but try using back-tick

```
select `id` AS 'member_id', 
`pd00` from `mbr` 
where `pd00` <> '';
```

Comment: Still tells me I have an error in syntax. Can't for the life of me see it. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''mbr'
 where 'pd00' <> '' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 2. Limit is added by the control panel automatically.

Answer (score 0):

LIKE and NOT LIKE will always return NULL if the column is NULL. You have to use a different operation.

IS NULL or NOT NULL would be a better choice.

You can compound the conditions to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're using the wrong quotes. Use ` for columns and tables.

Secondly, you should use `WHERE pd00 != ''` or `WHERE pd00 IS NOT NULL` depending on if it's an empty string, or null.